# Bing Maps Pushpin Click Event

Tags: android, sdk, maps, bing

I am building an android application with bing maps sdk.
I trying to implement event for pushpin click, some details will be show for the location.
I could not find any built in function for that purpose.
Is there any event listener for that?

Comment: have you get any idea for it ?